# C++ store string sentences from user input into a vector

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at C++ and currently learning vectors. Here is a simple code where program gets the user input and stores it in a vector then proceed to print the stored values from each element:

```
int main(){
vector<string> myVector;
string myInput;
int n;
cin>>n;
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
for(int i = 1; i <= n;i++){
  cout<<"loop count: "<<i<<endl; //added for checking the current loop
  getline(cin, myInput);
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
  myVector.push_back(myInput);
  }
for(unsigned int j = 0;j < myVector.size(); j++){
cout<<myVector[j]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

but when I run my code, during the user string input, it lets me enter two strings before finally going to the next loop. the program only prints out the first entered string for each loop though. So my questions are:

1) What is the reason behind this? Why does user need to enter two strings before going to next loop? Can someone explain to me.

2) how can this be fixed?

EDIT: Here are my sample inputs and the output:

input:

```
3
input loop count: 1
we are
the champions
input loop count: 2
no time
for losers
input loop count: 3
we are
the champions
```

output:

```
we are
no time
we are
```

Comment: As for your problem, can you please tell us the input you give the program, as well as the actual and expected output? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `getline` gets a whole line - including spaces. A space s a perfectly valid character to have in a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) call inside the loop.

The [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will silently eat up the trailing newline, but since you then call `ignore` you must enter a *second* line for `ignore` to be satisfied.

Simply remove the `ignore` call from the loop and it should work as you expect.

Comment: thanks! it actually fixed it. Also, thanks for the explanation why it happens

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put cin.clear(); cin.sync(); before getline function? cin and getline give you problems when you use them at the same time.